# SVG link with image (HTML)

Tags: html, image, svg, hyperlink, path

So I have a SVG file full of square paths. I'm trying to add images to those svg paths by adding a image over the square path in Inkscape. After I've added the image on top of the path, I embed the svg in my HTML file and add a link to that corresponding path. The issue I am facing is that it seems like the image I've inserted over the path it covering the link and not allowing me to click it. It does work without the image covering it, but the image gets thrown on top and it seems like its covering it and not allowing it to work any longer.

I've also tried the pointer-events:none option and I'm failing miserably so please explain in depth if that's the only way to solve the issue. My code is below:

HTML Code (editing the indidivual path by adding the link)

```
  <a
     href="https://www.google.com/"
     id="a53257">
    <path
       id="path106482"
       d="m 529.17,6e-7 v 5.2917 h -5.2917 V 6e-7 Z"
       fill="#0000ff" />
  </a>`
```

As for my SVG file its a grid full of path squares. I have added images over the top and sized them to cover the square paths. That is where my issue lies. Is there an easier way to add that image, such as adding the image in the path in Inkscape. Not an Inkscape expert so if there is an easier way to insert that image please let me know.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain an [mcve]. You say your problem is that an image covers the link. So your question should demonstrate that, i.e. it should contain an image that prevents us from clicking on the link should we try to do so.

Comment: Try moving the image inside the a. If this is not helping please add a relevant part of your code i.e the svg element with the a element the path and the image. Also probably it would be better to clip the image with the path or add the image to the path as a pattern